# How to collect values from a string when there are other qualifiers in Python?

Tags: python, jython

I have a string which contains phone numbers like the following sample:

`(808)555-1234^ORN^PP^^^^~^AAA^PP^^^^~(808)555-9876^ORN^CP^^^^`

Need to map two variables `Phone1` and `Phone2`, where `Phone1` is always followed by `PP` on the second instance after the upper caret `^` while `Phone2` is always followed by `CP` after the second caret of its instance.

The value for the `Phone2` can appear to be after the first or second `~` character.  It's not always in the same position.

End Desired Result

```
Phone1 = (808)555-1234
Phone2 = (808)555-9876
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem individually. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Given the many tutorials and examples for regex on line, you should be able to post an honest attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Remove '~', split on the repeat character, remove everything that's made of letters, `set()` to remove duplicates.

NOTE: This only works with this particular string, and will not generalize well

```
set(i for i in x.replace('~',"").split('^') if i.isalpha()==False and len(i)>0)
```